# Can I install ubuntu on my ssd and make the /home and /usr directory in the HDD that contains previous data?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I want to switch to Ubuntu. I have one SSD (120 GB)  and one HDD (1TB). I want to keep all the data of HDD and install the Ubuntu in SSD (only os) but I want to make the directory /home and /usr located in the HDD. [N.B I tried to make one of my HDD partition /home but the "format?" tab was ticked forcefully so I couldn't switch] Please let me know the complete procedure if  there any possibilities to keep the Hard Drive Data and also make it use for application installation location for Ubuntu. HDD have only one partition.

Comment: How large is SSD? You probably do not need /usr as separate partition. Most new users should use default install which is just / (root) and if UEFI,  the ESP partition. You can use a partition on HDD, but it must be Linux format like ext4. If NTFS, it cannot be /home & reformatting will erase it. Make sure you have good backups before doing anything. You also can keep /home inside / on SSD but add data partitions from HDD. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: What partitions currently exist on your HDD? Boot your install medium into "Try Ubuntu" mode, open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T` and type `sudo lsblk -f`. Update ([Edit]) your Question, don't Add comment.